# product attribute label value is empty

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, soap, product-attribute

With method catalogProductAttributeCreate SOAPv2 ver. 1.7.0.2 the product attribute label is "0" after creating the attribute, I expect "testlabel".

What is the correct XML code I have to use?

[image: product attribute label]

Comment: Is there any error you get? Maybe in system.log or error.log? Maybe you can start debugging in the _prepareDataForSave Method in Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Api and see what data comes in there?!

Comment: Can you provide example code of how you are creating it?